# postfix error unused parameter

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, linode

I need some help with the configuration of postfix. Doing it first time.

I'm following this how-to and configured each step carefully. 
Can anyone help me with this error pls?

```
Service postfix restart
* Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                                                                                     /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
                                                                                                                                                                [ OK ]
* Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                                                                                              
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_sasl_application_name=smtpd
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
```

Comment: i am following this how-to http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-10.04-lucid

Comment: What version of OS are you using and can you paste output of what version of postfix?

Comment: it's Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, postfix 2.9.6

Answer (score 6):

Okay so you are following the old how-to where they used postfix package with older version. With the version you've installed all that parameters outdated or got changed. You need to follow current postfix configuration guide.

In all those warnings Postfix, 
does not understand or interpret from your config. 
The alert is just there to tell you that expected behavior may not be as 
intended. So refer to `man 5 postconf` or review http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html for 
correct names and parameters.

Answer (score 4):

> smtpd_sasl_application_name (default: smtpd)
>          The  application name that the Postfix SMTP server uses for SASL server initialization. This controls the name
>          of the SASL configuration file. The default value is smtpd, corresponding to a SASL configuration  file  named
>          smtpd.conf.
>
> This feature is available in Postfix 2.1 and 2.2. With Postfix 2.3 it was renamed to smtpd_sasl_path.

The excerpt is from man pages. So basically replace it with

```
smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd
```

This worked for me.